# r data frame partial matching returns NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

Following data frame

```
> dx
   estyear age us_population
1    1980   0       3559857
2    1980   1       3315535
3    1981   0       3607440
4    1981   1       3436005
```

Split into groups

```
years <- c(dx[,'estyear'])
> years
[1] 1980 1980 1981 1981

dx.split <- split(dx, years)
> dx.split
$`1980`
   estyear age us_population
1    1980   0       3559857
2    1980   1       3315535

$`1981`
   estyear age us_population
3    1981   0       3607440
4    1981   1       3436005
```

Then return partial match subset by year. When passing a string literal the partial works just fine.

```
dx.split$'1980'
> dx.split$'1980'
   estyear age us_population
1    1980   0       3559857
2    1980   1       3315535
```

This is where the problem occurs. However, when passing a variable set to the same value it returns NULL.

```
selyear <- '1980'
> selyear
[1] "1980"

dx.split$selyear
> dx.split$selyear
NULL
```

Hopefully this is something simple.

The reason I want to use a variable is because I intend to iterate over the data frame by year driven by external inputs.  I am open to alternate paths that get to the same result and/or are easier

Thanks

Comment: Try `dx.split[[selyear]]` if you would like to return the `data.frame` or `dx.split[selyear]` if you would like the `data.frame` wrapped in a `list`.

Comment: @Jason Morgan  Thanks that worked perfectly.   My end goal is to extract age and us_population as vectors.  So the final form looks like this:   pop <- c(dx.split[[selyear]][,'us_population'])

Comment: You could use `lapply` to extract all of the `us_population` vectors into a list if you wanted to do that: `lapply(dx.split, `[[`, "us_population")`.